# ConnectivityManager is crashing while getting network info

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am new to Android and when I give the following snippet, my Android application is crashing.

```
ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI); // Application is crashing in this line.
```

I also checked the *AndroidManifest.xml* where I gave the Internet permission to the application. Any help would be really useful for my further work.

Comment: Could you add the Log Exception that you are getting? Also surrond by try a catch that piece of code and print the stack trace, would be usefull.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to say but if you want to check internet connection then you can use this code

```
/**
     * THIS IS FUNCTION FOR CHECKING INTERNET CONNECTION
     * @return TRUE IF INTERNET IS PRESENT ELSE RETURN FALSE
     */
    public boolean checkInternetConnection() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isAvailable() && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected());
    }
```

and dont forget

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone :) I have not specified ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission. And now everything is working fine. But to know about all these permissions is there any good reference. As i am not finding most of the permission related things in the docs?

Comment: Even though i added ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, my android app is still crashing.
I want to check whether wifi is enabled or not(I'm doing it using the code in the question)
Any other possible explanation for carsh?I'm getting error "ication permissions(process com.example.permissions) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again"

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: No you don't need ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION for the ConnectivityManager.

Comment: Neither INTERNET, at least for the purpose of getNetworkInfo().