# Internet Connection

Tags: android

i am using ConnectivityManager. i don't know what happen to my code it always return null if internet connected. plese help me.

```
public static boolean isOnline(Context ctx) {
    // Toast.makeText(ctx,"get", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ConnectivityManager mManager = (ConnectivityManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo mNetworkInfo = mManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if ((mNetworkInfo != null) && (mNetworkInfo.isConnected())) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
    }


        if (NetworkConnection.isOnline(TIENews.this)) {
            new GetNewsDetailAsyncTask(TIENews.this, url, newsListView)
                    .execute();
        } else {
            Log.e("tag", "netIno return null");
            super.OpenWiFiDialog(getResources().getString(
                    R.string.internet_error_msg));
        }
    }
```

thanks dear. my code was running fine before today and app is live also. but i dont know what happen during from last days to current time in this code and failed to run. and i ma not getting problem

Comment: check in manifest for Internet permission.Also your data plan/wi-fi is connected or not

Comment: Have you remembered to [grant access to android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6018405/1270789)?

Comment: Did you add permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"` to your manifest?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

Comment: pass `getApplicationContext()` as context in your `isOnline(getApplicationContext())`

Comment: i have given these all permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public class ConnectionDetector {

        private Context _context;

        public ConnectionDetector(Context context) {
            this._context = context;
        }

        public boolean isConnectingToInternet() {
            ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if (connectivity != null) {
                NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
                if (info != null)
                    for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                        if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                            return true;
                        }

            }
            return false;

Use this code. Its working
```

Answer (score 1):

The code seems to be fine. i think the problem with context i.e the context is null either Internet Permission in Manifest.. so please check it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you check the network if it exists or not :

```
ConnectivityManager
```

**method 1**

```
public boolean isConnected(){
  boolean result=false;
  ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext()
    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
  if (null != activeNetwork) {
            if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
             {
              result=true;
             msg="You are connected to a WiFi Network";
             }
            if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
            {
                result=true;
              msg="You are connected to a Mobile Network";
               }
            }   
  else{
   msg = "No internet Connectivity";
 result=false;
}

   return result;
 }
```

**method 2**

```
public  boolean isConnected() {
  ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext()
    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   // test
   if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
     && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
     && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {

   msg="You are connected to a Network";

   return true;
   } else {

    msg = "No internet Connectivity";

    return false;
   }
  }
```

Add this lines to your manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any bit of error in your code. May be the context is null.

Or you can simply try this simple line of code to check the internet connectivity...

```
// by default - its false
    private boolean isInternetConnected = false;

// Check the internet connectivity 

    isInternetConnected = Utilities.isInternetAvailable(MainActivity.this);

if(isInternetConnected){
  // perform here
}

public static boolean isInternetAvailable(Context context) {
        boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
        boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;
        boolean connectionavailable = false;
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
        NetworkInfo informationabtnet = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
            try {
                if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                   if (ni.isConnected())
                       haveConnectedWifi = true;
                if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                   if (ni.isConnected())
                       haveConnectedMobile = true;
                if (informationabtnet.isAvailable()
                       && informationabtnet.isConnected())
                   connectionavailable = true;

            } catch (Exception e) {

                System.out.println("Inside utils catch clause , exception is"
                       + e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
     }
```

**Also add the Internet Permission in your manifest.**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
public boolean isNetwokReachable() {
   ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) mSmartAndroidActivity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   if (connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() .isConnected()) {
       return true;
   } else {
       return false;
   }
}
```

Add below required permission in AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```